# Thoughts on Home Security Camera Location

Tags: security

We are building a new home and now is the time to run CAT5/6 for IP cameras I have planned.  The system can support more than 4 cameras, but that's what I'm think of starting with for now.

I've marked the areas I'm thinking in red. The house has a courtyard where the pool is. I'd like a camera on the pool, the driveway, the back of the house, and the front east corner.  I know there are some blind spots, I'm not looking for 100% coverage. But this will get most of everything coming and going.

[image: house plans]

Comment: can you pan the cameras? If so, you really want them on the outside corners instead of the inside ones; basically where you would place a bartizan on a castle.

Comment: What's the question here? It's not opinion based, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a new build, I would run wiring to every corner (including inside corners) and just put a cover plate on the ones you aren't using. Small cost up front, but tons of flexibility. Make sure the CAT cables are clearly labelled at the switch side of things.

Answer (score 1):

I like to have cameras cover all of the doors in the house.  I use the cameras to watch for guests or see when a package was dropped off.  I like to think the cameras are for "watching the state of the house", more than "catching criminals".

Comment: Yes I agree.  It's more so the "state of the house."

Answer (score 1):

#### Conduit

As mentioned in numerous other questions, if you run conduit to each location then you will have maximum future flexibility. CAT 5/6 is plenty for today's cameras, but (a) you may want multiple cables in the future (e.g., a second camera, WiFi extender, etc.) and (b) you may want fiber in the future, or some enhanced CAT 'n'. Many houses around today were built long before Ethernet (even the old coaxial type) or even before any digital computers existed! Starting with a new house, you don't want to limit yourself to today's technology. Conduit gives you flexibility.